# Left join with additional join condition on Raima

Tags: sql, rdbms, raima

I am struggeling with a `left join` on a Raima database. I'd like to add an additional join condition, but in this case the join behaves like an inner join, thus I am losing some of the expected results.

Example:

`TABLE_A`

```
 ID        
-------    
 1         
 2         
 3         
 4
```

.
`TABLE_B`

```
 A_ID | B 
 --------
  1   | 1
  2   | 1 
  2   | 2
  3   | 2
```

Query

```
select * from TABLE_A left join TABLE_B
on TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_B.A_ID
and TABLE_B.B = 1
```

I am expecting the following result:

```
1   1   1
2   2   1
3 null null
4 null null
```

E.g. on an Oracle 11g I get the expected result, but on the Raima it shows me only the first two results. What is the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: How does where condition `B.B =1` gives you expected result in `oracle`.? Seems incorrect to me.

Comment: There is no `where` condition in my SQL statement.

Comment: Ok I understand. Oracle is using `and TABLE_B.B = 1` in join condition but  Raima is not(somehow. I dont know exactly why). Hence the discrepancy. To avoid it, please use the query like I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
select * from A left join 
(select * from B where B=1) bd
on A.ID = bd.A_ID
```

The query you gave will not give you expected result in oracle also. This will.

PS: Please use different names for `table` and `column`

Comment: "the query you gave will not give you expected result in oracle also" ... Yes, it does! I tested it just a few minutes ago. Just wondering why it does not work on Raima

Comment: Try the query which I gave in answer.

Comment: Seems like Raima does not support such sub-selects.

Comment: Strange as most db supports it. Try creating a view, say `bd` as `select * from B where B=1` and use that view in the `join`.